.eslintrc to eslint.config.mjs -> errors while migrating to the new config syntax
Here's my old .eslintrc


{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      },
      "alias": {
        "map": [
          ["@renderer", "./src/renderer"],
          ["@components", "./src/renderer/components"],
          ["@common", "./src/common"],
          ["@main", "./src/main"],
          ["@src", "./src"],
          ["@misc", "./misc"],
          ["@assets", "./assets"]
        ],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    },
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
  }
}



Here's my new eslint.config.mjs


// eslint.config.js
import globals from 'globals'
import eslintPluginReact from 'eslint-plugin-react'
import typescriptEslint from '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'

const filesList = ['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.jsx', 'src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.tsx']

export default [
  'eslint:recommended',
  /*
  {
    files: filesList,
    plugins: {
      react: eslintPluginReact
    },
    rules: {
      ...eslintPluginReact.configs.recommended.rules
    }
  },
  */
  typescriptEslint.recommended,
  {
    files: filesList,
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2022,
      sourceType: 'module',
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.node
      }
    },
    extends: [
      'eslint:recommended',
      'plugin:react/recommended',
      'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
      'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
      'plugin:import/errors',
      'plugin:import/warnings'
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    settings: {
      'import/resolver': {
        node: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
        },
        alias: {
          map: [
            ['@renderer', './src/renderer'],
            ['@components', './src/renderer/components'],
            ['@common', './src/common'],
            ['@main', './src/main'],
            ['@src', './src'],
            ['@misc', './misc'],
            ['@assets', './assets']
          ],
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
        }
      },
      react: {
        version: 'detect'
      }
    },
    rules: {
      'react/prop-types': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off'
    }
  }
]



eslint doesn't like it:
"TypeError: Config (unnamed): Unexpected non-object config at user-defined index 0."
to any external configuration that used to be inside "extends".
I guess that I miss something but there's neither documentation nor examples how to do it.

The config file must export an array of configuration objects, strings is not allowed.
It's mentioned in Migration Guide:
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
    js.configs.recommended,
    ...
];

